# Communication between containers in docker swarm

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I would like to communicate between master and worker nodes via WebSocket connection in docker swarm mode.

A master node should have been reached from the worker node. 
The connection fails.

Also, I would like to connect via http to the master node from my host machine. The connection fails as well.

Here is my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  master:
    image: master
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/master/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./config.env
    command: ['node', './src/master/']
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - webnet
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.2"
          memory: 200M
      restart_policy:
        condition: none

  worker:
    image: worker
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/worker/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./config.env
    command: ['node', './src/worker/']
    deploy:
      replicas: 10
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 100M
      restart_policy:
        condition: none
    networks:
      - webnet
    depends_on:
      - master

networks:
  webnet:
```

I create the swarm with:

```sh
docker swarm init
docker-compose build --no-cache
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml ${stack_name}
```

I try to reach the master node with:

```sh
curl http://localhost:8080/result
```

and get

```sh
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
```

Some more details about **master** node:

*Env:*

```
MASTER_PORT=3000
MASTER_HOST=localhost
MASTER_HTTP_PORT=8080
```

*Code starting websocket server:*

```
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ host: config.masterHost, port: config.masterPort }, (err) => {
  if (err != null) {
    throw err
  }
  console.log(`Web Socket server started on address ws://${config.masterHost}:${config.masterPort}`)
});
```

*Code starting http server:*

```
server.listen(config.masterHttpPort, config.masterHost, (err) => {
    if (err != null) {
      throw err
    }
    console.log(`Http server started on address http://${config.masterHost}:${config.masterHttpPort}`);
  });
```

Some more details about **worker** node:

*Env*

```
MASTER_SERVICE_HOST=master
MASTER_PORT=3000
```

*Code connecting websocket client to master node:*

```
const masterUri = `ws://${config.masterServiceHost}:${config.masterPort}`;
console.log(`Connecting to ${masterUri}`);
const ws = new WebSocket(masterUri, {perMessageDeflate: false});
```

#### I'm really confused because when I'm  running the app with docker-compose (not in swarm mode) everything works perfectly.

But in swarm mode, I neither could reach

**the master node from host machine via http**

nor could I reach

**the master node from worker node via websocket connection**

I suspect me configuring the docker networking incorrectly.

Logs from **master** node:

```
Process started with config: {
  "grouperFile": "./src/operations/group.js",
  "initialDelay": 10,
  "mapperFile": "./src/operations/map.js",
  "masterHost": "localhost",
  "masterHttpPort": 8080,
  "masterPort": 3000,
  "masterServiceHost": "master",
  "slaveReplicationFactor": 1
}
Web Socket server started on address ws://localhost:3000
Http server started on address http://localhost:8080
```

Also, some logs from **worker** node:

```
Process started with config: {
  "grouperFile": "./src/operations/group.js",
  "initialDelay": 10,
  "mapperFile": "./src/operations/map.js",
  "masterHost": "master",
  "masterHttpPort": 8080,
  "masterPort": 3000,
  "slaveReplicationFactor": 1
}
Connecting to ws://master:3000
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN master master:3000
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at ClientRequest.req.on (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:554:10)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Comment: I you sure that master not is up and running?

Comment: Master is up and running since *worker* depends on *master*.

Comment: Post logs from both of services: ```docker service logs [service_name]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
Web Socket server started on address ws://localhost:3000
Http server started on address http://localhost:8080
```

Don't bind to localhost. Bind to any IP 0.0.0.0.
Or for more security bind to `hostname -I` IP
For all outside your container is not localhost it's another host despite you run on the same machine.

Comment: So, I need to run my servers on 0.0.0.0:3000 and 0.0.0.0:8080?

Comment: In plain compose I am able to connect via service name.  am I able to do it in swarm mode as well?

Comment: Yep... You can't bind to localhost and query from outside. Just try put new bind to you application

Comment: Communication between containers is done in the same way?

Comment: Communication between containers is equal to communication between machines